# Knockout.js complex object binding results empty HTML output

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem on populating data using Knockout.js.
Data (A HomeViewModel having 9 MainMenuModel) is successfully retrieved from Web API.
I expect 9 li tag under ul tag. But HTML output is empty. Tried hard but can't solve.
I appreciate any help, thanks.

Data Model Acquired from Web API

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public List<MainMenuModel> MainMenus { get; set; }
}
public class MainMenuModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Knockout script

```
function MenusViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.menus = ko.observableArray([]);
   var baseUri = '/api/Home';
   $.getJSON(baseUri, function (data) {
       self.menus = data.MainMenus;
   });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  ko.applyBindings(new MenusViewModel(), document.getElementById('mainMenus'));
});
```

_MainMenu.cshtml (Partial View)

```
<ul id="mainMenus" data-bind="foreach: menus">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: $data.Url, title: $data.Name }, text: $data.Name"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

HTML Output

```
<ul id="mainMenus" data-bind="foreach: menus"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ko.observable` and `ko.observableArray` are functions. To assign them a new value you need to call them with the new value as the argument.

See also the documentation: [Reading and writing observables.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading_and_writing_observables)

So change your code in `$.getJSON` to:

```
$.getJSON(baseUri, function (data) {
    self.menus(data.MainMenus);
});
```